# Trying to write to a mysql database but it keeps coming up empty set

Tags: php, mysql

For a school project I am trying to write to a table called `enrolment` where the student number and the course they have selected are added after they have been tested to make sure the student name and number exists in another database. No errors are coming up, however when I check my database afterward `enrolment` says its an empty set. Does anyone have suggestions?

```
<?php

require 'connect.php';

//making a variable from the user data
$name = $_POST["name"];
$number = $_POST["snumber"];
$course = $_POST["pcourse"];

//linking up the database
$link = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASS, DB) or die (mysqli_connect_error());

// select all from table student which show student name and number
$squery = "SELECT * FROM student";
$sresult = mysqli_query($link, $squery);

$found = 0;

while ($srow = mysqli_fetch_array($sresult)) {

    // testing if the student name and number match the users data
    if ($name == $srow['family'] && $number == $srow['uid']) {

        $enrol = "INSERT INTO enrolment (uid course) VALUES('$number' '$course')";
        $found = 1;
        break;
    }
}
mysqli_close($link);

?>

<html>
    <body>
        <form action="index.php" method="post">
            <br>
            <input type = "submit" value="back" name="back">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

index.php (form)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Course Selection</h1><br>


    <form action="next.php" method="post">


              Name: <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required="required" maxlength="50">
              <br><br>

              Student Number: <input type="text" name= "snumber" required="required" maxlength="9">
              <br><br>

        <?php
        //form
      require 'connect.php';

       echo "Select a course: <select name = \"pcourse\">\n";

      $link = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASS, DB) or die(mysqli_connect_error());

      $query = "SELECT * FROM course";
      $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<option> $row[code] $row[name] $row[maxenroll]</option><br>";
      }

      mysqli_free_result($results);

      mysqli_close ($link);

      echo " </select>\n";


      ?>

      <br><br>
      <input type = "submit" value="submit" name= "submit">

    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I don't understand the point of the SELECT

Comment: thank you for shadowing your password and username, I'm so happy I got to find it on at least 1 PHP question

Comment: Where are you collecting user data from , you don't have any input from HTML

Comment: You're not executing any insert query; just creating a string called `$enrol`

Comment: `(uid course)` and `('$number' '$course')` should be comma-seperated

Comment: Check this for making your insert statement secure: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496

Comment: And why are you selecting every record from the student table? Haven't yu ever seen a WHERE clause in a SQL query?

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says **[you may be at risk for SQL Injection Attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/)**. Learn about [Prepared Statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) with [parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4712113/5827005). I recommend `PDO`, which I [wrote a class for](https://github.com/GrumpyCrouton/GrumpyPDO) to make it extremely easy, clean, and more secure than using non-parameterized queries. Also, [This article](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/mysqli_comparison) may help you choose between `MySQLi` and `PDO`

Answer (score 0):

Your insert code just a string. You should send to mysql your insert code. Try this

```
$enrol = "INSERT INTO enrolment (uid, course) VALUES($number, $course)";
$link->query($enrol);
```

Comment: this will fail.

Answer (score -2):

My guess is that when checking the result set from `student` table - there is no such `family` and `uid` in it, which means - in the table. Instead of doing insert right away, try to display matching record from the database - if this is actually what you wanted to find. Then you can check what is actually stored in the database - and you can compare both.
Other thing is - why not limit select to exact that student? 
Rebuild your query, something like: 
`$squery = "select * from student where family='".$name."' and uid='".$number."'"`. 
Then you can check how many records were selected and display that number before doing any inserts.